# Progmatically genereated emails for Outlook get stuck in Drafts folder even after being sent!

Tags: c#, outlook

So I have been generating emails through a C# application for the company I work for. Emails are generated fine. The only little issue is that when they are sent from the drafts folder, they are not moved to the sent folder. They stay in the drafts folder.

I didnt know if it was a setting on the email or not

Here is the code I used:

```
Outlook.Application objOutlook= new Outlook.Application();

        // Creating a new Outlook Message from the Outlook Application Instance
        // Assigns the "TO", "CC" and "BCC" Fields
       // Assigns the Subject Field

        Outlook._NameSpace oNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
        String body;
        Outlook.MailItem mic = (Outlook.MailItem)(objOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
         mic.To = receiver;
         //Code that fills in body and what not of the email
         mic.Subject = subject;
         mic.HTMLBody = body;
         mic.SaveSentMessageFolder = folder
         mic.Save();
```

Maybe some one has a idea? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is saving the emails in the Drafts folder after being sent because you asked it to save it there.

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder folder
    = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
...
mic.SaveSentMessageFolder = folder
```

[Per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171932%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

> ...a MAPIFolder object that represents the folder in which a copy of the e-mail message will be saved after being sent.